# Asp.Net Mvc Load Image (img src) from Byte[] in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm developing an application with ASP.Net Mvc4, Razor and javscript/Jquery.
I need to display images that are stored on a remote server, these images will fall within a component "slider".

I recover the address remote of the images and these store them in a List of byte[] from controller with json.
The Class ByteImages:

```
     public class ByteImagenes {
        public byte[] byimagen { get; set; }
        public ByteImagenes(byte[] byImagen) {
            byimagen = byImagen;
        }
     }
```

The Action Controller:

```
    public JsonResult AlbumFoto(string Directorio){
        var Lista = Galeria(true, Directorio);
        return Json(new { Fotos = Lista });
    }

     private List<ByteImagenes> Galeria(bool Remoto, string Directorio){
        string path = string.Empty;
        DirectoryInfo dir = null;
        List<ByteImagenes> flistImagenes = new List<ByteImagenes>();
        if (!Remoto){
            path = "/" + Directorio + "/";
            dir = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + Directorio);
        }
        else {
            path = Directorio;
            dir = new DirectoryInfo(Directorio);
        }
        FileInfo[] fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var fileQuery = from file in fileList
                        where ((file.Extension == ".jpg") ||
                               (file.Extension == ".png") ||
                               (file.Extension == ".gif") ||
                               (file.Extension == ".jpeg"))
                        orderby file.Name
                        select file;
        foreach (var file in fileQuery){
            var b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + file.Name);
            flistImagenes.Add(new ByteImagenes(b));
        }
        return flistImagenes;
    }
```

In the View, I'm creating my gallery pictures in a function javascript.
In this function javascript I can't show the images.
function javascript:

```
   function CrearGaleria(data) {
    var elem;
    $.each(data.Fotos, function (key, val) {
        var _ParamImp = val.byimagen;
        var link2 = '@Html.Raw("data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Param)")';
        link2 = link2.replace("Param", _ParamImp);
        alert(link2);
        elem = "<li><a><img src=" + link2 + " /></a></li>";
        $("#ulImages").append(elem);
    })
    iniciarEfecto();
}
```

the alert(link2)this show me:
[image]

I can't load the image in src from array byte how I can resolve this problem?

**EDIT** I can resolve this problem...
I change my class before byte[] now string

```
public class Imagenes
{
    public string imagen { get; set; }
    public Imagenes(string sImagen)
    {
        imagen = sImagen;
    }
}
```

and when load the values I change in private List Galeria in foreach Convert.ToBase64String

```
foreach (var file in fileQuery)
        {
            var b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + file.Name);                
            listImagenes.Add(new Imagenes(Convert.ToBase64String(b)));
        }
        return listImagenes;
```

and in javascript in the view:

```
function CrearGaleria(data) {
    var elem;
    $.each(data.Fotos, function (key, val) {
        elem = '<li><a><img src="data:image;base64,' + val.imagen + '"/></a></li>';           
        $("#ulImages").append(elem);
    })
    iniciarEfecto();
}
```

Now I can show the images. :-)

Comment: Maybe you could mark the byte-Array as not serializable (if I'm not wrong by adding the attribute [ScriptIgnore]) and add a getter returning Base64-values?

Comment: Hi @Mister Henson I probed and not function